# What's is going wrong with this "Check for Palindromes" JS Function?

Tags: javascript

I'm practising some JS exercise, and got stuck with this palindromes function. There is something I'm not been able to figure  out, my code is not splitting the string into an array.

```
    function palindrome(str) {
  var re = (/[^\w]/g);
  str.replace(re).toLowerCase();
 var Newstr= str.split().reverse().join('');
  if(str=== Newstr){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }

}



palindrome("eye");
palindrome("not a palindrome"); //not working for this str.
```

So how the split() should be presented in the code so that it works.

Comment: `str.replace(re).toLowerCase();` --- what's this? What "not working" actually means?

Comment: `code str=str.toLowerCase();
 var Newstr= str.split('').reverse().join(''); `  .Why do you need to use the regex here?

Comment: @zerkms, by this I'm replacing all the non characters and punctuation with  blank, so that the string will be joined means no space, comma or anything. Here's not working means this function doesn't return "false" for the third and last string, which it supposed to be.

Comment: @user2906838 you need to assign it somewhere. Plus `replace` accepts 2 arguments.

Comment: @Varun, I just want to remove all those space and comma from the string.

Comment: @zerkms, even if I pass two argument like this `str= str.replace(re,'');` it doesn't work!

Comment: @user2906838 "it does not work" is not helpful, seriously. Learn to debug your code.

Comment: @zerkms, apologize for this time, Yes I need to learn to debug. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
    var reverseStr = str.split("").reverse().join('');
    return str === reverseStr;
}
```

This fixes several problems in your original code:

1. You were calling `.replace()`, but not passing the 2nd argument to replace it with anything.
2. `.replace()` returns a new string so you have to assign the result to something in order to use the result of the replace operation.
3. You were calling `.split()` with no arguments which doesn't actually split it.  You should call it as `.split("")` to split it into an array of characters.

Working snippet that logs results:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
    str = str.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
    var reverseStr = str.split("").reverse().join('');
    var result = (str === reverseStr);
    log(str + ": " + reverseStr + ": " + result);
    return result;
}

function log(x) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.textContent = x;
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}

palindrome("eye");
palindrome("race car");
palindrome("not a palindrome"); //not working for this str.
palindrome("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama");
palindrome("never odd or even");
palindrome("nope");  //not working for this str.
```

Comment: Added explanation for what was wrong with OP's code and added working embedded code snippet.

Comment: I think `"A man, a plan, a canal. Panama"` should be treated as a palindrome actually

Comment: @zerkms - fixed that - thx.  I wasn't sure exactly what the replacement rules were.

Comment: @jfriend00 and zerkms , I got it. Thank you for the explanation. It helps me a lot

Comment: new to stack. Thanks